# Open-source alternatives to Google Datastore

Tags: database, google-apps, nosql

I want to free my data from lock-in to Google Datastore. But I can't find alternatives that are

- Schemaless (so I can port my mass of schemaless data) rich query
  capability)
- Allow queries against any field or combination (Datastore
  allows that, so long as you predefine the index)
- Not require sharding

There are thousands of DBMSs out there, how do I go about finding such an alternative?